# Pandas : How to combine two cells with same values into one singular cell in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am filtering this data from a snowflake table. After doing the group by's and setting the first two columns as index my dataframe looks like this
[image: My Current Dataframe]

[image: What I want it to look like]

I set the index and tried a bunch of group by statements as well but none of them work because of unique IDs. I want to format it to an HTML and send a report and hence I want it look this way

Comment: To me it seams like you would want to do this on the html front end. Are you using a python web framework, If so which one?

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook to create data frame, what you see here is .to_html() version of it